# How to have multiple django requirements file mentioned in fig file for docker deployment across dev, staging and prod servers?

Tags: python, django, docker, requirements.txt, fig

I just wrote my first fig file. It makes working with docker really awesome.

I want fig to launch my local, staging, and prod containers as well. So I wrote 3 different fig files. fig-dev.yml, fig-stage.yml and fig-prod.yml.

The three yml files contain the images that needs to be pulled as per the requirements of the 3 servers.

In my django applications, I have 3 different requirements file(local requirements, staging requirements, and production). I wanted to specify each of the three in the yml files. Since we can run the `pip install *-requirements.txt` only in the Dockerfile.

There is no way, I can pull the code to different servers, and while building it, I can pass flags as to which requirements file to install things from.

There is an [issue on fig](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/85), which asks for support for multiple Dockerfiles. Is there any way, I can pull code, pass flag to specify, which requirements to install from?

Thanks!

Comment: well, fig is essentially for development only.